# product of delta functions as a Fourier transform

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

A delta function can be represented as an integral using its Fourier-representation:

\begin{equation}
\delta\left(\vec{s}_j^2-1\right)=\int \frac{\mathrm{d} m}{2 \pi} \exp \left\{-\mathrm{i} m\left(\vec{s}_j^2-1\right)\right\}
\end{equation}

I have $N$ vectors: $\left\{\vec{s}_1,\vec{s}_2,\dots,\vec{s}_N \right\}$ and would like to use the Fourier representation of:
$$\prod_j\delta\left(\vec{s}_j^2-1\right)$$

Can I use one integral variable like this:
\begin{align}
\prod_i\delta\left(\vec{s}_i^2-1\right)&=\int \prod_j\left(\frac{\mathrm{d} m}{2 \pi} \exp \left\{-\mathrm{i} m\left(\vec{s}_j^2-1\right)\right\}\right)\\
&=\int \frac{\mathrm{d} m}{(2 \pi)^N} \exp \left\{-\mathrm{i} m\sum_j\left(\vec{s}_j^2-1\right)\right\}
\end{align}

Or do I need to introduce $N$ distinct integration variables like this:

\begin{align}
\prod_j\delta\left(\vec{s}_j^2-1\right)&=\int \prod_j\left(\frac{\mathrm{d} m_j}{2 \pi} \exp \left\{-\mathrm{i} m_j\left(\vec{s}_j^2-1\right)\right\}\right)\\
&=\int \prod_j\left(\frac{\mathrm{d} m_j}{2 \pi}\right) \exp \left\{-\mathrm{i} \sum_jm_j\left(\vec{s}_j^2-1\right)\right\}
\end{align}

Are both representations correct?